# GWT hello world app does not compile and asks for 'com.google.gwt.core.Core'

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I haven't done GWT development for a while and wanted to try again. In my Windows 10, I installed JDK 12 and Eclipse 2019-03. I installed GWT Eclipse Plugin (GWT 2.8.1).

From Eclipse, I created a hello world project this way:

1. Click on 'New GWT Application Project'
2. Project name: Gwt5, Package: com.foo, Use default SDK (GWT 2.8.1)
3. Click on 'GWT Compile Project'

I see this error:

```
Compiling module com.foo.Gwt5
   [ERROR] Hint: Check that your module inherits 'com.google.gwt.core.Core' either directly or indirectly (most often by inheriting module 'com.google.gwt.user.User')
```

I didn't change my gwt.xml. I checked and `"com.google.gwt.user.User"` is there.

Any suggestion?

Comment: and what is the language level for the project, did you try with language level 8?

Comment: You pinpointed the issue. Thanks! I tried setting language compliance level to 1.1 and downloaded Oracle's JDK 11. I didn't realize I had to go way back to Java 8 + JDK 1.8.

Answer (score 2):

When language compliance level or JRE is set to higher than what GWT supports, this error occurs (The error message is not very helpful though).

As of May 2019, GWT supports only up to Java 8, and that is provided by JDK 1.8. For example, to make GWT work with Oracle's JDK, you need to download an **older** version of JDK (Java SE), than set both the **Compiler compliance level** and **Installed JRE** to:

1. Compiler compliance level: 1.8
2. JRE Home: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\`

Comment: This is incorrect - GWT 2.8.2 is the current version (as of May 2019), which supports _language level_ of Java 1.8, but can run on newer JVMs (I've personally tested up to 11). GWT 2.8.2 was released Oct 2017 - if you decide to use an older version of GWT than that, you may be more restricted (like 2.8.1 in your post). http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html http://www.gwtproject.org/download.html